# Dúvidas quanto a variável $_GET

Tags: php, get, slim

Eu tenho esse formulario de pesquisa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E estou recebendo o valor dela pelo $_GET nesta rota

```js
$app->get("/search", function()
{
 $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
 
 $pagination = Product::getPageSearchSite($_GET, $page);

 $pages = [];
 
 for ($x = 0; $x < $pagination['pages']; $x++)
 {
  array_push($pages, [
   'link'=>'/search?'. http_build_query([
   'page'=>$x+1,
   'search'=>$_GET
   ]),
   'text'=>$x+1
  ]);
 }

  $page = new Page();  
 
  $page->setTpl("search", array(
   "products"=>$pagination['data'],
   "search" =>$_GET,
   "pages"=>$pages

  ));   
});
```

Que envia a variavel para o metodo getPageSearch, onde ele realiza a paginação e pega os valores da busca..

```html
 public static function getPageSearchSite($value, $page = 1, $itemsPerPage = 3)
 { 
  $idproduct = $value["searchbycode"];
  $vlobject = $value["searchbyobject"];
  $vltype = $value["searchbytype"];
  $vlcategory = $value["searchbycategory"];
  $vlbedroom = $value["searchbybedroom"];
  $idcity = $value["searchbycity"];
  $vlprice = $value["searchbyprice"];

  $start = ($page - 1) * $itemsPerPage;
  $sql = new Sql();

  $query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tb_products a INNER JOIN tb_photoproducts b USING (idphoto) INNER JOIN tb_cities c USING (idcity) WHERE 1 = 1 ";
   
  if($value["searchbycode"] != ""){  
   $sql->select($query .= " AND idproduct = ".  $idproduct);
  }
  if($value["searchbyobject"] != ""){  
   $sql->select($query .= " AND vlobject = '" . $vlobject . "'");
  }
  if($value["searchbytype"] != ""){  
   $sql->select($query .= " AND vltype = '" . $vltype . "'");
  }
  if($value["searchbycategory"] != ""){  
   $sql->select($query .= " AND vlcategory = '" . $vlcategory . "'");
  }
  if($value["searchbybedroom"] != ""){  
   $sql->select($query .= " AND vlbedroom = '" . $vlbedroom . "'");
  }
  if($value["searchbycity"] != ""){  
   $sql->select($query .= " AND idcity = '" . $idcity . "'");
  } 
  if($value["searchbyprice"] != ""){
   
   if($value["searchbyprice"] == 1){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 0 AND vlprice <= 100000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 2){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 100000 AND vlprice <= 200000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 3){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 200000 AND vlprice <= 400000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 4){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 400000 AND vlprice <= 600000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 5){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 600000 AND vlprice <= 800000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 6){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 800000 AND vlprice <= 1000000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 7){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 1000000 AND vlprice <= 1400000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 8){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 1400000 AND vlprice <= 1600000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 9){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 1600000 AND vlprice <= 1800000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 10){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 1800000 AND vlprice <= 2000000 ");
   }
   else if($value["searchbyprice"] == 11){
    $sql->select($query .= " AND vlprice >= 2000000 ");
   }
  } 
  
  $results = $sql->select($query .= " LIMIT $start, $itemsPerPage;");
  $resultTotal = $sql->select("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS nrtotal;");
  return [
   'data'=>$results, //todos resultados da consulta
   'total'=>(int)$resultTotal[0]["nrtotal"], //numero totol de registros
   'pages'=>ceil($resultTotal[0]["nrtotal"] / $itemsPerPage) //tot de pag*ceial arredonda pra cima
  ];
 }
```

O problema é que na primeira busca funciona, a variavel $value que ele recebe esta no formato de array e ele preenche as variaveis ali,  mas na segunda vez quando clica para ir para alguma pagina e ele envia o $_GET para  o método getPageSearchSite() o valor recebido esta em formato da URL e ele nao consegue pegar as variaveis, não consigo descobrir porque esta acontecendo isso.

Comment: Mas por que você está passando $_GET como um parâmetro do método ? não tem necessidade

Comment: Mas qual alternativa eu tenho? eu estou enviando porque preciso pesquisar no banco os valores recebidos do campo de busca que estão no $_Get.

Comment: Você não precisa passar ele como um parametro do método, basta acessar o $_GET lá de dentro, e ele vai trazer os resultados corretamente